# "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" But can't see why it is accessing an integer

Tags: django, django-forms

I can't see why in my application i am getting this error. As all primary keys are text fields are integers. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
 class EventAttendForm(forms.Form):
     talk = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Talk.objects.all())
     membersAttended = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.all())
```

models.py

```
 class Talk(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)  
 class Member(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
     talks = models.ManyToManyField(Talk, through='Event_Attendance')
 class Event_Attendance(models.Model):
     talk = models.ForeignKey('Talk')
     membersAttended = models.ForeignKey('Member')
```

views.py

```
 def addAttendance(request):
     #eventAttendanceForm
     if request.method == 'POST':
          eventAttendForm = EventAttendForm(request.POST)
      for member in request.POST['membersAttended']:
            ea = Event_Attendance(request.POST['talk'], member)
            ea.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../../../talks/')      
else:
    eventAttendForm = EventAttendForm()
    return render_to_response('attendance/addAttendance.html',{'eventAttendForm': eventAttendForm})
```

I cannot see why I am getting this error. The exact error is:

```
 Exception Type:    ValueError
 Exception Value:   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'redirectTest'
```

RedirectTest is a Talk that I created with my form for the add talk to check that redirection was working correctly. The line of code that it is saying is causing the problem is `ea.save()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the line

```
ea = Event_Attendance(request.POST['talk'], member)
```

You are creating an instance of the model `Event_Attendance`. The constructor expects the first argument to be an instance of `Talk`. Instead you are supplying it with a string which is the *title of the talk*.

A quick fix would be to look up the `Talk` instance with the matching title and pass it as an argument to the constructor. Something like this:

```
talk = Talk.objects.get(title = request.POST['talk'])
ea = Event_Attendance(talk = talk, membersAttended = member)
ea.save()
```

This will work but is not the best way to go about it. For one, the first line can always raise a `DoesNotExist` if a `Talk` with the given title is not found. Second you are accessing the `POST` variables directly rather than using the `Form` to validate them.

A better answer would therefore be:

```
eventAttendForm = EventAttendForm(request.POST.copy())
if eventAttendForm.is_valid():
    talk = eventAttendForm.cleaned_data['talk']
    membersAttended = eventAttendForm.cleaned_data['membersAttended']

    for member in membersAttended:
        ea = Event_Attendance(talk = talk, membersAttended = member)
        ea.save()
```

Comment: Having tried this i am now getting this error: 
`int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Talk'`

Comment: Thanks again for the new edit. Im still learning python(im moving from java). :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the keyword args! Fixed it.